# context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified vs context.Update(x) what is the difference?

Tags: entity-framework-core

What is the difference between `context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified` vs `context.Update(x)`? They seem to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is with the [related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data). The former just sets the state of the entity, while the later performs recursively the same for all reachable entities through navigation properties. As mentioned in the documentation link:

> **Tip**
>
> Use the `EntityEntry.State` property to set the state of just a single entity. For example, `context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Modified`.

So if you don't have related data (navigation properties), there is no difference, If you do have, then the first method (setting `State`) gives you more granular control (less side effects) while the second (`Update`) might lead to unexpected behaviors - basically marking all related entities and their content as modified/added and then try to insert new or update a lot of records which are not supposed to.